# Build failed 'React/RCTBridgeModule.h' file not found

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, cocoapods

I spent my day trying to fix my problem, I tried every solution I found in other SO posts but unfortunately I can't figure out how to solve my problem.

I try to integrate TouchID inside my react-native project. I downloaded a npm package called "react-native-touch-id" (sounds perfects !). I followed installation guide and I manually linked library to my project.

But when I try to run application I get the following error :

[image: main problem image]
[image]

I tried to clean my project :

- rm -rf node_modules
- yarn cache clean && yarn install
- rm -rf ios/Pods/ && pod install

In xCode I even clean the build folder.

About my versions :

- RN : 0.57.4
- xCode : 10.1
- react-native-touch-id : 4.3.0

Here's my Podfile :

```
def available_pods
  pod 'TouchID', :path => "../node_modules/react-native-touch-id"
end
target 'App' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!
  available_pods
end
```

I added the .xcodeproj of react-native-touch-id package inside my project's libraries directory and in Build Phases I linked it.

[image]
[image]

But I still getting the same error again and again ... I don't understand why ... If someone have an idea some help would be really appreciated :)

Comment: Do you really need the use_frameworks! and available_pods lines in your pod file? If not I suggest you remove those lines and clean install npm modules and pods as you previously did.

Comment: Do you have "React" schema selected for your project from the product menu?

Comment: I remove use_frameworks! line from my Podfile but same error as before ... 
@helloworld Yeah it's selected and top of the list

Comment: Xcode gives me this error when there's a mismatch between minimum iOS targets between my app's project file and a pod's project file., ie when the pod's minimum target is higher than the app's.

Comment: use 56.0.0 is best version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appeared the problem was the Podfile. It seems that Podfile use its own Podspec which caused troubles. So I simply delete the TouchId pod declaration from my Podfile, clean and re-install my pods.

Then, I manually linked the library to my xcode workspace. To do that, under your project name, **Right Click on Libraries directory => Add files to "your project name" => Add the xcodeproj of the npm's package located inside your node_modules directory**.

After that, in your project **Build Phases** under the **Link Binary with Libraries** you have to add the npm's package static library (example libTouchID.a in my case).

To be sure you can clean your project and try to rebuild, it should work now.

For information, I kept all of my softwares version I mentionned above.

Answer (score -1):

If it shows react native(missing) in

> product->scheme->manage scheme->project name->build

1. remove the ios folder
2. react-native eject
3. cd ios/
4. pod init
5. pod install
6. cd ..
7. react-native link
8. cd ios
9. open *.xcworkspace/

this happens when the react native package is not linked properly to the ios build. The npm link does it.

Comment: It’s not a good idea to use `react-native eject`.  Furthermore if you upgrade your Xcode version to the actual newest 11.0 with RN0.60 you don’t even need to link anymore thanks to the auto linking provided by this RN version.

Comment: for older version of react native we still need it

Comment: I prefer manual linking it’s safer but you’re right for older version we need to link package. Anyway don’t advise to eject project.